# How to stop macbook from playing youtube videos at login screen?

Tags: login, youtube

When I opened my macbook this morning, a youtube video I had been watching earlier started playing at max volume.

Combine that with the touch keyboard, so there's no way to adjust the volume until I log in..

Basically a terrible user experience. Is there any way to not autoplay media when I open the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

**Option A:** Simply hit the speaker icon (Mute key) on login.

Using the *Apple Keyboard*
[image: Apple Pro Keyboard layout with function keys]

Using a MacBoook *with Touch Bar*
[image: MacBook Touch Bar]

**Option B**: Global setting to turn off websites that automatically play media.

Open Safari > Preferences > Websites > When visiting other websites > **Stop Media with Sound**

[image: Safari Auto-Play Preferences]

Comment: This mac has a touchbar, there is no mute button :(

Comment: I have updated my answer. You will also find a mute Button on Macs with Touch Bar. Additionally I have added a alternative workaround.